# Black/white patches on betta

Tags: health, fish

I have a betta fish that I got about a month ago, and just started noticing black patches on him, and one white patch underneath his gills. He still acts like his usual self, he still eats, and is pretty active, but I want to be sure he isn’t sick or anything. He is in a 3 gallon tank filtered and heated from 78-80 degrees, and I do 25% water changes every week.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. On this site we require people to concentrate on one question per post. Does [this post](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18829/12501) answer your question about the black spots? Then please [edit] your post and limit it to the white spot. If not, you can always create a second post for your second question. Please also include information about your latest water test results (nitrite, ammonia, ph) and whether or not you have [cycled your tank](https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing visual on your beta would be concerning to me. Many fish exhibit color changes for years even after they are born and developed enough to be considered mature. I'm going to guess it's just his natural color developing over time unless there are other signs of stress or illness. If it starts looking like cotton or the texture of his scales or skin changes, that would be a sign of some sort of infection, but based on the picture, it looks like color only to me which should be fine.